# Change css/less based on user language or preferences language Odoo 10

Tags: alignment, stylesheet, odoo-10

Dears I am using Odoo 10. My requirement is bit different and I am not finding any such questions or answers on any forum. Actually I want to change the alignments of my text and icons based on user language or preferences selected language. I have created a custom module and I am able to use my custom styling. My xml file is as follows:

```
<odoo>
  <data>

<template id="assets_backend" name="project_extend assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">

<xpath expr="." position="inside">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/project_extend/static/src/less/form_view_extra.less"/>

</xpath>

</template>

        <record id="project.edit_project" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">project.project.form</field>
            <field name="model">project.project</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <form string="Project">
                <sheet string="Project">
                    <field name="analytic_account_id" invisible="1" required="0"/>
                    <div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box" groups="base.group_user">


                        <button  class="oe_stat_button" name="attachment_tree_view" type="object" icon="fa-files-o">

                            <field string="Documents" name="doc_count" widget="statinfo"/>

                        </button>

                        <button class="oe_stat_button" type="action" attrs="{'invisible':[('use_tasks','=', False)]}"
                            name="%(project.act_project_project_2_project_task_all)d" icon="fa-tasks">
                            <field string="Tasks" name="task_count" widget="statinfo" options="{'label_field': 'label_tasks'}"/>
                        </button>

                        <button name="toggle_active" type="object"
                                confirm="(Un)archiving a project automatically (un)archives its tasks and issues. Do you want to proceed?"
                                class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-archive">
                            <field name="active" widget="boolean_button"
                                options='{"terminology": "archive"}'/>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oe_title">
                        <h1>
                            <field name="name" placeholder="Project Name"/>
                        </h1>
                        <div name="options_active" class="oe_edit_only">
                            <div>
                                <field name="use_tasks" class="oe_inline"/>
                                <label for="use_tasks" class="oe_inline" string="Tasks"/>
                                <span attrs="{'invisible':[('use_tasks', '=', False)]}">as </span>
                                <field name="label_tasks" class="oe_inline oe_input_align" attrs="{'invisible': [('use_tasks', '=', False)]}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <notebook>
                        <page name="settings" string="Settings">
                            <group>
                                <field name="user_id" string="Project Manager"
                                        attrs="{'readonly':[('active','=',False)]}"/>
                                <field name="privacy_visibility" widget="radio"/>
                                <field name="partner_id" string="Customer"/>
                            </group>
                            <group name="misc">
                                <group string="Configuration" groups="base.group_no_one">
                                    <field name="sequence" groups="base.group_no_one"/>
                                </group>
                                <group string="Time Scheduling" groups="base.group_no_one">
                                    <field name="resource_calendar_id" groups="base.group_no_one"/>
                                </group>
                            </group>
                        </page>
                        <page name="emails" string="Emails" attrs="{'invisible': [('alias_domain', '=', False)]}">
                            <group name="group_alias">
                                <label for="alias_name" string="Email Alias"/>
                                <div name="alias_def">
                                    <field name="alias_id" class="oe_read_only oe_inline"
                                            string="Email Alias" required="0"/>
                                    <div class="oe_edit_only oe_inline" name="edit_alias" style="display: inline;" >
                                        <field name="alias_name" class="oe_inline"/>@<field name="alias_domain" class="oe_inline" readonly="1"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <label for="alias_model" string="Incoming Emails create" class="oe_edit_only"/>
                                <field name="alias_model" class="oe_inline oe_edit_only" nolabel="1"/>
                                <field name="alias_contact" class="oe_inline oe_edit_only"
                                        string="Accept Emails From"/>
                            </group>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
                <div class="oe_chatter">
                    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" help="Follow this project to automatically track the events associated to tasks and issues of this project." groups="base.group_user"/>
                </div>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="hr_timesheet.project_invoice_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Inherit project form : Invoicing Data</field>
            <field name="model">project.project</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.edit_project"/>
            <field name="priority">24</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <button name="toggle_active" position="before">
                    <button class="oe_stat_button" name="%(hr_timesheet.act_hr_timesheet_line_by_project)d" type="action" icon="fa-calendar" string="Timesheets" attrs="{'invisible': [('allow_timesheets', '=', False)]}" style="text-align:right"/>
                </button>
                <field name="user_id" position="after">
                    <field name="subtask_project_id" groups="base.group_no_one" attrs="{'invisible': [('allow_timesheets', '=', False)]}"/>
                </field>
                <xpath expr="//div[@name='options_active']" position="inside">
                    <div>
                        <field name="allow_timesheets" class="oe_inline" string="Allow timesheets"/>
                        <label for="allow_timesheets"/>
                    </div>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>


  </data>
</odoo>
```

As you can see in the beginning I am including stylesheet which is working perfectly. Now I want to compare the user/preferences language. If it is arabic language then stylesheet should be included else if user/preference language is english the the stylesheet should not be included so that the default alignment in odoo should come in effect. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I haven't try this but after reading your question I got an idea that this might be possible by JS. You can able to get which language is currently there and apply css like wise from JS.